# Why does ajax setup not work in this scenario?

Tags: jquery

From a request to the server I am returning a 401 error.

I would like to handle this and redirect the user appropriately.

At first I tried to use the ajaxSetup to capture the error and handle it, but this doesn't get hit.

Then I changed it to use the ajaxError method, and this works.

Why is it not hitting the error method when I use ajaxSetup?

This works:

```
$("body").ajaxError(
                function (e, request) {
                    if (request.status == 401) {
                        alert("Your session has expired. Please login again to continue.");
                        window.location = "/admin/account/logon";
                    }
                }
            );
```

But this doesn't work:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) {
            if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                alert("Your session has expired. Please login again to continue.");
                window.location = "/admin/account/logon";
            }
        }
    });
```

It is triggered using Jquery Unobtrusive Ajax, and the link looks like this:

```
<a title="Delete this comment" class="close " data-ajax="true" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this comment?" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#Comments" href="/myurl">×</a>
```

Comment: Use $(document) and not $(body). Also, I don't understand the question, are you asking _why_ the jQuery syntax works like that?

Comment: in your ajax call are you registering more error handlers? share how you are making the ajax call

Comment: I've updated the question with the additional details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) :

```
Note: 
Global callback functions should be set with their respective global Ajax event handler methods—
.ajaxStart(),
 .ajaxStop(),
 .ajaxComplete(),
 .ajaxError(),
 .ajaxSuccess(),
 .ajaxSend()

—rather than within the options object for $.ajaxSetup().
```